# yfrak fonts are rasterized in the newest MikTeX-portable

Tags: fonts, installing-fonts

I tried the following code with pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{yfrak}\selectfont A
\end{document}
```

If I use the newest MikTeX-portable, then the output:

[image]

If I use the full TeX Live 2017, then the output:

[image]

So in MikTeX-portable the yfrak fonts are rasterized, but in TeX Live they are not. What should I do in MikTeX-portable?

Comment: The MiKTeX distribution doesn't contain the  type 1 version of these fonts. You'll have  to download them, more precisely ` yfonts-t1.zip` from CTAN, install them in your TeXMF-local rootdirectory (create it if you don't have one), refresh the FDB and run from the command line (as administrator) `updmap.exe`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found only yfonts.zip on CTAN here: https://ctan.org/pkg/yfonts-t1. I installed it in texmf-local, then I refreshed FDB, finally updmap, but the result is nothing:(

Comment: You need to add the map-file also to a `updmap.cfg`. Without it updmap will do nothing. I made a feature request that the fonts are added to miktex. Meanwhile it should work if you add `\pdfmapfile{=yfrak.map}` to your document.